# Changing HISTTIMEFORMAT leaves entries with incorrect date

Tags: bash, command-history

After exporting `HISTTIMEFORMAT='%F %T'` I tried to query history

But the result shows all the commands are executed on same day.

How can I check the actual date and time of actual command execution?